# Display all the rides for which the travel duration is more than 2 hours

Tags: oracle

Sample output:
Rise_ID FROM_LOCATION TO_LOCATION SEATS_LEFT
SEATS_TOTAL RIDE_PROVIDER START_ON ENDS _ON IS_STARTED IS_FINISHED 12014 Nandi hills banglore 0 3 11002 13-Nov-20
04.00.13.36 PM. 13-Dec-20 08.02.13.36PM yes yes

Answer (score 0):

one way  you can get the difference between the 2 date columns as follows.
If the following SQL SYSDATE is getting the current time, the other column is a hard coded date time column.

```
SELECT     ROUND(minutes_ / 60, 2) || ' Hours ' 
FROM     ( SELECT  (sysdate - to_date('14/09/2022 19:35:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) * 24 * 60     AS minutes_
  FROM     dual
);
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT FROM_LOCATION || ' - ' || TO_LOCATION
FROM TABLE_OUTPUT T
WHERE (TO_DATE(START_ON, 'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS') - TO_DATE(ENDS_ON, 'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS')) > 2;

I assuming you are looking this data from a table, also you need to check the format, the current you're using not gonna work, i suggest the format 'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).